# wrong number of arguments error in select tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this select tag code in my view 
`Task <%= select_tag :timesheet_task_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@timesheet_tasks, 'id', 'name', @timesheet_task_id), + grouped_options_for_select(grouped_task_options, @timesheet_task_id), prompt: '<All Tasks>' %>`

I am getting this error 
"wrong number of arguments (given 4, expected 1..3)"
and the following code is shown below in the error 
`module FormTagHelper
      **def select_tag_with_non_empty_blank_option(name, option_tags = nil, options = {})**
        if options.delete(:include_blank)
          options[:prompt] = '&nbsp;'.html_safe
        end`

Could anybody please help me with  this? I want to know what is wrong with the select tag statement.

Comment: The issue is passing four parameters, which is what you're doing. Did you  mean to concatenate the `o_f_c_f_s` and `g_o_f_s` results as a single parameter?

Comment: yes that is what i intend to do

Comment: This got solved ... a small comma in between is what was causing the error.